# How do I fit a GLM in R given an ex-gaussian distribution of the dependent variable?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I'm trying to fit a glm in R
My code is the following:

```
mod1 <- glm(formula = DV ~ IV1*IV2, data = df).
```

where IV1: between-subjects independent variable;
IV2: within-subject independent variable

The DV distribution (not the residual!) is approximately an ex-gaussian.

Which "family" argument should I use?
Any tips are welcome, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure DV is ex-gaussian?  What is your justification for this?

Comment: library(gamlss)
library(gamlss.dist)
library(gamlss.add)

fit <- fitDist(df$DV, k = 2, type = "realplus", trace = FALSE, try.gamlss = TRUE)
This is the output that I get from this: Family:  c("exGAUS", "ex-Gaussian") 
Fitting method: "nlminb"

Comment: That performs maximum likelihood estimation (I presume) on the *marginal* distribution.  Regression concerns the *conditional* distribution (the distribution of the outcome conditioned on the predictors).  This is not a valid justification for an ex-gaussian family. See my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/398553/111259) for more on this.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this! May I ask you I could I determine (accurately) the ***conditional*** distribution of the data? with code, possibly?

Comment: Can you tell us more about DV?  What is it?  How is it measured?

Comment: the DV consists of a continuous variable. Its values could range from 0 to 100. Given a statement, participants had to answer using a VAS scale ranging from 0 = “strongly disagree” to 50 = “neither agree nor disagree” to 100 = “strongly agree”.

Comment: and DV can take on any value from 0 to 100?  Could it take 47.7 for example, or is it restricted to whole numbers?

Comment: it can take any value

Comment: More important to understand how the variance is related to the mean, but i strongly suggest you stop looking at your data to choose your models. What sort of quantity does your response variable measure - e.g. is it a time, a length, a proportion, a count, an angle, ...etc? When you say it can take any value, do you mean it can be negative? If not, could some values be exactly 0?

Comment: I should clarify -- I am not suggesting that *looking at data* is a bad way to come up with a model, just that using *the same data* you want to use for inference to choose a model has undesirable properties.